# What do you want to do in Rio?

Tags: discussion, site-promotion

Four weeks from tomorrow (at this writing) is March 5, the deadline for submitting abstracts for Short Communications for the ICM 2018 (International Congress of Mathematicians) happening In the first 9 days of this coming August, in Rio de Janeiro in Brazil.

The Congress organizers ask for registration first before abstract submission, but about a month after abstract acceptance is when early registration is finalized (meaning pay any money), so no financial commitment is needed to submit an abstract before the deadline.  I encourage many who have publishable work to share to consider submitting an abstract. (Start with http://www.icm2018.org . I can add some words about the submission process for those interested.)

I have also done efforts to promote MathOverflow at the two past ICM's. (Thanks again to those who helped, especially Charles Siegel, Scott Morrison, and Mariano Suarez-Alvarez.) If you know you are attending and wish to do some MathOverflow related activities at the Congress, this thread is to help with the planning and organization of such activities.  If you are unsure or know you are not attending but would like to help, participating in this thread is one way to do that.

One thing that became clear to me from the last ICM was that three months was not enough prep time to do a good job at promotion.  It is my hope that this coming ICM will see enough time and community effort spent in helping MathOverflow grow into the global resource it can be.  I also hope it will encourage more members to participate in meetups, and that one of them will happen in Rio in August.

So, what (MathOverflow-related) things do you want to see in Rio?

Gerhard "That Time Of Century Again" Paseman, 2018.02.04.

Answer (score 29):

If you have an excuse to mention MO in your abstract, please consider doing so. MO is mentioned in [the paper I submitted for the proceedings](http://www.math.tamu.edu/~bill.johnson/mainREVISED.pdf) and it will appear in one slide of my talk at the ICM.

Answer (score 4):

I am adding this post to encourage suggestions from and for attendees (and requests from those who will not attend).  Opening Ceremonies are less than four days from this writing!

[The scientific program](http://www.icm2018.org/portal/en/program-at-a-glance) is posted at the website for ICM2018.  I hope to attend the opening and closing ceremonies, and many events in between.  There are two receptions for registered members on Tuesday and Wednesday, and for those who opted in a social gathering/dinner on Saturday (31, 1, and 4).  There are other opportunities to gather, and I encourage attendees who want to meet up to post other suggestions.

For those who are not attending, you can ask about a specific talk or presentation, or other Congress activity, and those who follow this thread may respond to it briefly here.  I recommend posting requests as comments for now.

I will be collecting information about the Congress, especially regarding logistics.  If you are there, your first line of help should be the Congress volunteers.  This thread can be a third line of help, but I will be checking it about three times a day at wide intervals, so this is not a good place for urgent issues.  I will respond as quickly as I can from Friday the 3rd on, and less so before.

**Some notes 07.31**

There is a shuttle available from two of the airports to RioCentro for registered members and their families. Check the website for details, but I believe it is from Tobim (GIG) and San Tomas airports from 7a.m. to midnight for the next two days.

It is raining now. Dress accordingly.

Check for updates to the venues.  Unconfirmed info suggests Pavilion 3 will not host the plenary and other lectures as planned earlier.

Oh, and use Credit Cards. The tariff for buying BReals at the airport with USD got me less than 2.5 BReals per dollar, as opposed to over 3.

The rapid bus system (BRT) takes some getting used to, but it is an affordable option. Ask for help if you have trouble finding and using the system maps as I did.  Bus 51 stops at RioCentro and Olof Palme (or what ever the next station name is), with the latter a little closer to the Registration Pavilion and my choice when it rains.  Bus 51 also stops at a couple of transfer points, and I use one of them to head West on a different bus towards downtown, Copacabana, and the hostel I'm at.

Hopefully Wi-Fi will improve. That was one reason why I left tonight's reception early, so I could write this.

**Notes 08.01**

Indeed, Opening Ceremonies are in Pavilion 6.  They have recorded jungle sounds, possibly to cover algebraic geometry chatter.  Or not.

**More Notes 08.08**

There is a sign up at registration for (free) transportation from RioCentro to the airport(s), with buses leaving between 16:30 and 20:00.  Ask at the desk for more details.

**Notes 08.09**

Be sure to check out icm2018.org in the days to come for more material, as well as the upcoming website (which I bet is called) icm2022.org for the next ICM.  Sign up for shuttle transportation to the airport from RioCentro if you have not done so.

Gerhard "Be Seeing You From Rio" Paseman, 2018.07.28.

Comment: Will anyone be attending Geordie Williamson's plenary lecture on Wednesday the 8th? I am very curious about that one (not that I expect him to once again reveal some huge result at a lecture, but his talks are still usually well worth the time).

Comment: I hope to be at Williamson's talk. I will see what material (e.g. video) is being released by the organizers about the plenary lectures.  Gerhard "Been Arriving Late Each Morning" Paseman, 2018.08.03.

Comment: @Tobias, according to the organizing chairman, there will be some days before the videos of the plenary lectures are released. I intend to be at the talk.  If I hear gasps from the audience, I will take a picture of the slide.  Gerhard "If It Is Family Appropriate" Paseman, 2018.08.04.

Comment: Thank you. As I said, I don't expect any big revelation, but it is good to know that the talk will be available (his abstract seems like it will be more general than allows for big reveals, but then again, in Uppsala 2012 he decided to completely change the topic compared to the announced abstract since the work had just been completed).

Comment: @Tobias, I found a lovely introduction into representation theory for the first part of Williamson's lecture.  I did not stay riveted though, and lost some of the middle. He mentioned Kazhdan-Lustig, a new character formula, and a billiards conjecture. In a few hours, someone will post an overview of this, and the proceedings will contain much detail.  Gerhard "Hope This Helps A Bit" Paseman, 2018.08.08.

Comment: Thank you. Where will the overview be posted? The topics mentioned are at least ones I am very much familiar with.

Comment: I don't know . Tomorrow I will ask about availability of the abstracts and videos. A version of the abstract is available on the website right now, and a blurb for mass consumption should be posted later tonight (as they have done with earlier plenary talks).  Send me an email, and I can send you some snaps I took.  Gerhard "Almost Ready To Go Home" Paseman, 2018.08.08.

Comment: Do you know if there has been any update on the expected time for these videos? Or maybe other sources for them (I know that Scholze's talk is on the uni-bonn youtube channel now).

Comment: @Tobias, I do not know.  I will make some inquiries later today.  Gerhard "Hopefully I'll Get Good News" Paseman, 2018.08.30.

Answer (score 2):

The Social Dinner (for those who reserved places) is about to start (at this writing, in a little more than 30 minutes).  I will have a MathOverflow table , both for socializing and for promoting the forum.  I invite others to join me and talk about the Congress and the forum.

Gerhard "Promises To Be Quite Entertaining" Paseman, 2018.08.04.

Answer (score 0):

The 2018 edition of ICM has come to an end, with Smirnov and Okounkov inviting mathematicians (and others) to St Petersburg, Russia for the next edition in 2022.  Travel grants and related funding will be made available to some; if you fit the category or think you do, now is not too early to start planning.  There are other efforts on which they request international help, so check their website for information about this.

Gerhard "Made It Through Number Nine" Paseman, 2018.08.04.